# IRC Python Bot: Best Way

Tags: python, irc, bots

I want to build a bot that basically does the following:

1. Listens to the room and interacts with users and encourages them to PM the bot.
2. Once a user has PMed the bot engage with the client using various AI techniques.

Should I just use the IRC library or Sockets in python or do I need more of a bot framework.

What would you do?

Thanks!

Here is the code I'm currently using, however, I haven't gotten it to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import socket
network = 'holmes.freenet.net'
port = 6667
irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
irc.connect ( ( network, port ) )
irc.send ( 'NICK PyIRC\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'USER PyIRC PyIRC PyIRC :Python IRC\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'JOIN #pyirc\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG #pyirc :Can you hear me?\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'PART #pyirc\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'QUIT\r\n' )
irc.close()
```

Comment: I'm close to finishing an IRC package for Python which might be able to help you out. I'll have it available here: http://ircutils.evanfosmark.com/

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  I'll keep this in mind!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) or [Asynchat](http://docs.python.org/library/asynchat.html) if you want to have a sane design. It is possible to just do it with sockets but why bother doing it from scratch?

Comment: I just checked out Twisted again and found it under the IM section.  Thanks for the link.  What exactly does the Asynchat help with?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have AI techniques involved, then I suggest you look at the [AIML](http://pyaiml.sourceforge.net/) package for Python. It is the same technology that ALICE bots are done in.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the AIML package!

Answer (score 5):

If what you want is to create the AI portion, why bother writing all the code needed for the IRC connection by yourself?

I suggest using [SupyBot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/supybot/), and simply write your AI-code as a plugin for it. There is reasonably understandable documentation and lots of example-code to find. Also, it comes with a decent amount of plugins for all sorts of uses that might complement your AI.

Answer (score 4):

As I'm replying ~2 years later, I'm writing this just for Googlers :-P

Just try my 'Yet Another Useless IRC Bot' here https://github.com/julienpalard/yauib permitting you to code each feature of your bot using whatever language you want.

Answer (score 2):

I made a (very crappy, and for a long time being refactored) [IRC bot](https://github.com/xiongchiamiov/mpu/) using [irclib](http://python-irclib.sourceforge.net/).  The documentation is next-to-nothing, but it gets rid of making you have to do all that socket connecting and such, which is stuff I really don't want to deal with.  To each his own, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use an existing IRC library instead of implementing the protocol yourself.