# Looking for multiple things in a string

Tags: python, irc, bots

I am trying to make a script that opens a url when the OPEN command is entered. This is for an IRC bot I am creating. I am trying to make it like this

OPEN http://url.com and it opens the url. This is what I have so far.

```
import webbrowser
test = s.recv(1024)

if test.find("http://") != 1:
        webbrowser.open(test)

else:
    print "it didnt work"
```

I honestly have no idea how this is done.

Comment: Er, what is what you have so far?

Comment: Second Blorgbeard.  The code *is* worth posting (I hope :)

Comment: Post up the code, it might help us to understand what you're getting at a bit better. Just insert comments saying what should happen where you haven't got real code yet.

Comment: I did, I really don't understand how this is done.

Comment: I am trying to make it so from my irc client I could wrute OPEN http://google.com and it would open that URL on a computer running the python script.

Comment: @Max: Is that all? Where does the IRC bot come in play? I mean, you can't just connect and read. You need to implement the IRC protocol. I think using the `webbrowser` module is a good solution for the actual URL opening part, though.

Comment: Hey dude, maybe check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100840/irc-python-bot-best-way

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions? `re.match(r'OPEN .*',line)` would be a pretty useful start.

Comment: @NiklasB. That is not the important part. I have all the other parts written already I just need this part done now.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

```
import webbrowser
#command is OPEN http://url.com
a = raw_input("Command: ")

if "OPEN" in a:
    url = a.strip("OPEN ")
    webbrowser.open(url)
```